# f:convertDateTime not showing date after I enter slash

Tags: jsf, primefaces, filter, datatable

So, I have a PrimeFaces datatable:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{taskTableBean.finishedTasks}" var="ot" tableStyle="width:auto" paginator="true"  rows="15">
   <p:column headerText="Task Number" style="width:50px;">
       #{ot.plannedTaskId}
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="Planned start date" filterBy="#{ot.plannedStartDate}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
      <h:outputText value="#{ot.plannedStartDate}">
         <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
      </h:outputText>
   </p:column> 
...
```

I don't have anything behind on logic specifically for this date, just this tags.

My problem is: 
When I start to enter date, specifically the day into field, is all good. Data table filter is good, but when I enter Slash / all data disappears and "No records" shows.

Comment: Built-in filtering is good for Strings, not 'contains' on dates (the date objects does not contain a '/'). I don't have the time to write a solution since I never use built-in filtering but always use lazy datamodels. Creating a custom filter is most likely what you need